Customizing User Creation in Strapi
In Strapi, is it possible to have controllers for "users-permission" table?
in account creation, i want to create a username automatically.
i will create with user's name. I added this new field in the table.
i'm thinking of creating it like this
if the user's name is "David Jones"
it's username is gonna be "david-jones-4"
4 is his id. the id of the last record before him was 3.
and to make sure it's unique, attach 3 to 4 digits of random generated strings (a-zA-Z0-9) to that username.
I want to do that username creation on backend.
the process of creating that username is doable but to think of where to do that, i thought we would do like that in controllers, right? but i can't find a default controller for it.
for example: there is a product table inside my database. and the location of the controller is backend\src\api\product\controllers\product.ts.
i couldn't find where i could configure that "users-permission" table and all too. like i wanted to remove that default username column but couldn't find where i could do that. and at least i wanted to do that username column nullable but couldn't find where i could do that?

You would have to extend or modify the users permission controller/service.
You can accomplish this via the register function found in the root of your Strapi folder in the src/index.js file.
Here is a link in for the exmaple.
https://github.com/strapi/internal-lms/blob/00f19ae839a58332b52ac9e6570085ee1ddc22c9/backend/src/index.js#L30
What we are doing is we are getting the service that we want to modify and overiding it with our custom logic.
strapi.plugins["users-permissions"].services["providers"].connect

With this line we are finding the connect service and then passing our function to overide the core service.
You can find the original code here
In the provided example we are overiding the provider but for your case you would do something like this.
strapi.plugins["users-permissions"].controllers["auth"].register 


To modify the register controller with your logic.
You would need to use the original code found here inorder to extend/overide the controller.  https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/aff9d09e4edf4d38b8a0de5abf83d79bedb28313/packages/plugins/users-permissions/server/controllers/auth.js#L293
async register(ctx) {
    const pluginStore = await strapi.store({ type: 'plugin', name: 'users-permissions' });

    const settings = await pluginStore.get({ key: 'advanced' });

    if (!settings.allow_register) {
      throw new ApplicationError('Register action is currently disabled');
    }

    const { register } = strapi.config.get('plugin.users-permissions');
    const alwaysAllowedKeys = ['username', 'password', 'email'];
    const userModel = strapi.contentTypes['plugin::users-permissions.user'];
    const { attributes } = userModel;

    const nonWritable = getNonWritableAttributes(userModel);

    const allowedKeys = compact(
      concat(
        alwaysAllowedKeys,
        isArray(register?.allowedFields)
          ? // Note that we do not filter allowedFields in case a user explicitly chooses to allow a private or otherwise omitted field on registration
            register.allowedFields // if null or undefined, compact will remove it
          : // to prevent breaking changes, if allowedFields is not set in config, we only remove private and known dangerous user schema fields
            // TODO V5: allowedFields defaults to [] when undefined and remove this case
            Object.keys(attributes).filter(
              (key) =>
                !nonWritable.includes(key) &&
                !attributes[key].private &&
                ![
                  // many of these are included in nonWritable, but we'll list them again to be safe and since we're removing this code in v5 anyway
                  // Strapi user schema fields
                  'confirmed',
                  'blocked',
                  'confirmationToken',
                  'resetPasswordToken',
                  'provider',
                  'id',
                  'role',
                  // other Strapi fields that might be added
                  'createdAt',
                  'updatedAt',
                  'createdBy',
                  'updatedBy',
                  'publishedAt', // d&p
                  'strapi_reviewWorkflows_stage', // review workflows
                ].includes(key)
            )
      )
    );

    const params = {
      ..._.pick(ctx.request.body, allowedKeys),
      provider: 'local',
    };

    await validateRegisterBody(params);

    const role = await strapi
      .query('plugin::users-permissions.role')
      .findOne({ where: { type: settings.default_role } });

    if (!role) {
      throw new ApplicationError('Impossible to find the default role');
    }

    const { email, username, provider } = params;

    const identifierFilter = {
      $or: [
        { email: email.toLowerCase() },
        { username: email.toLowerCase() },
        { username },
        { email: username },
      ],
    };

    const conflictingUserCount = await strapi.query('plugin::users-permissions.user').count({
      where: { ...identifierFilter, provider },
    });

    if (conflictingUserCount > 0) {
      throw new ApplicationError('Email or Username are already taken');
    }

    if (settings.unique_email) {
      const conflictingUserCount = await strapi.query('plugin::users-permissions.user').count({
        where: { ...identifierFilter },
      });

      if (conflictingUserCount > 0) {
        throw new ApplicationError('Email or Username are already taken');
      }
    }


// YOU WOULD DO SOME LOGIC HERE AND YOU CAN PASS IT TO THE newUser object


    const newUser = {
      ...params,
      role: role.id,
      email: email.toLowerCase(),
      username,
      confirmed: !settings.email_confirmation,
    };

    const user = await getService('user').add(newUser);

    const sanitizedUser = await sanitizeUser(user, ctx);

    if (settings.email_confirmation) {
      try {
        await getService('user').sendConfirmationEmail(sanitizedUser);
      } catch (err) {
        throw new ApplicationError(err.message);
      }

      return ctx.send({ user: sanitizedUser });
    }

    const jwt = getService('jwt').issue(_.pick(user, ['id']));

    return ctx.send({
      jwt,
      user: sanitizedUser,
    });
  },

Sorry if this may be confusing.  It is not as straight forward.
We do have open office hours on Strapi's Discord server Monday - Friday 12:30 pm CST, if you need more help you can stop by.
